# Call Javascript Function on hyperlink click and wait for animation to finish?

Tags: javascript, css, transition, page-transition

I have a page-out transition animation that I am using with css. It relies on changing the class of a container to start a css animation. I'm looking for a way to activate this animation (by adding the class to the container) then waiting for it to finish, then go to the link the href has. Here is the
[JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/81w35r42/8/)

```html
       <div class="navigationbar">
            <a href="home.html">
                <h2 class="logo">The Lowdown.</h2>
            </a>    
            <ul>
                <li><a href="text.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="edition.html">EDITIONS</a></li>
                <li><a href="articles.html">ARTICLES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="https:/google.com">HOME</a></li>
                
              </ul>
        </div>

        
<div class="loader loader--active">
    <div class="loader__icon">
    </div>
    <div class="loader__tile"></div>
    <div class="loader__tile"></div>
    <div class="loader__tile"></div>
    <div class="loader__tile"></div>
    <div class="loader__tile"></div>
    <div class="loader__tile"></div>
  </div>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below solution, if it works for you

```
var el = document;
//el.onclick = showFoo;

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".jqLink").on("click",function(event){
var myRef=this;
console.log("ref=>",$(myRef).attr("href"));
showFoo(event);
setTimeout(function(){

 $loader.classList.remove('loader--active');
 
 setTimeout(function(){
 window.location.href=$(myRef).attr("href");
 },1000);
},2000);
});

})

function showFoo(e) {
  $loader.classList.add('loader--active');
  return e.preventDefault();
}

var $loader = document.querySelector('.loader')

window.onload = function() {
  $loader.classList.remove('loader--active')
};

  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $loader.classList.remove('loader--active')
  }, 2000)
```

Add "jqLink" css class to your every  element, like below

```
 <li><a href="text.html" class="jqLink">CONTACT US</a></li>
  <li><a href="edition.html" class="jqLink">EDITIONS</a></li>
  <li><a href="articles.html" class="jqLink">ARTICLES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#aboutus" class="jqLink">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="https:/google.com" class="jqLink">HOME</a></li>
```

Try this, if it works for you.